# Replacement to Event Generators in Weblogic

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am trying to use the Event generators in a later version of Weblogic. 
Currently I am using the Event Generators in Weblogic 10.3.1, and it is working fine.
But in the later versions of weblogic when I am tryin  to use them they are not being able to be invoked.

After some investigation its found that the Event generators are now only on Oracle SOA Suite enabled Weblogic.

But I am not permitted to use SOA Suite for Weblogic.

Is there an alternative for Event Generators which is found in Weblogic 11g or 12c ?

If not what will be the alternative to do to invoke time scheduling in Weblogic server.

Should I write code for invoking time-triggered jobs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean WebLogic Integration Event Generator? As I know, WebLogic Integration does not supported now and Oracle SOA Suite is a recomended replacement for this one. Oracle SOA Suite contains a Event Delivery Network - the new technology for Event Driven Architecture implementation. But you wan't use Oracle SOA Suite and EDN.

You can use Open Source solutions, i.e. [Guava EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). Or you can implement EDN alternative themself (EDN based on Oracle AQ, but can work on JMS message infrastructure, you can emulate events using any messages and JMS Topic for subscribing on that "events").